# boost::asio keep a dead connection ESTABLISHED forever

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

I have a server program written in `C++` with `boost::asio` that has this strange behavior.

If a client initiate a connection with the server but is killed with sigfault before finishing the `TCP` stays `ESTABLISHED` forever.

The server reader code is:

```
void interface_connection::read_header()
{
    boost::asio::async_read(m_socket,
            boost::asio::buffer(&m_request_header, sizeof(m_request_header)),
            boost::bind(&interface_connection::read_header_cb, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

The keep alive parameters are set to 600 seconds

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 600
```

Comment: if you have the other end killed, you may not get a disconnection ACK until you read again on the socket and until the keepalive expires, and this may take a looong time, also you will not get data-ready notifications in an event driven loop, so the best thing is always to implement your own heartbeat scheme, or just bind a timestamp to the last-read operation on a socket, and abort any socket that expires the timeout

Comment: but the fact is that even the keep-alive is not respected. I got established connections with more than 4 days after the client died.

Comment: as I said before, if you do not force a read on the socket, even the keepalive expired, you'll never get a disconnection